# Is it possible to make a forest plot output smaller/resize? Forestplot doesn´t fit the screen (using packages “meta” and “metafor” in R)

Tags: r, resize, image-resizing, r-forestplot

We're performing a meta-analyses in R with the packages "meta" and "metafor". This is working well, however when we make a figure, it doesn't fit the screen. Names of articles are falling of, the upper and lowest lines are not visible. We've tried to smaller font size etc, but that is not solving the problem.

CODE:

```
subganal.study.qual=rma(yi, vi, data=ies.logit.qual.nomis, mods=~study.qual, method="DL")
pes.summary.study.qual.nomis=metaprop(Positive, Total, study, data=db.nomis.qual, sm="PLO", method.tau="DL", method.ci="NAsm", byvar=study.qual,tau.common=TRUE, tau.preset=sqrt(subganal.study.qual$tau2))

forest(pes.summary.study.qual.nomis)
```

[image: See for example of forest plot here]

Answer (score 0):

As it is a base plot, we can set the margins:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)

# default margin
x <- par()
x$mar
# [1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, main = "Default margin: 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1")

# set bigger margins
par(mar = c(6, 6, 6, 6))
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, main = "Bigger margin: 6, 6, 6, 6")
```

[image]

[image]