# Forest plot cut off (package "meta)

Tags: r

Hello I'm trying to create a forest plot but its cut off and need help.

[image]

- I have tried already following the advice of adjusting the xlim (from [R - Quick question about narrowing plot of the forest plot using metafor package; too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420337/r-quick-question-about-narrowing-plot-of-the-forest-plot-using-metafor-package)) but all it does is distorting the odds ratio scale.

  `forest(total_res$test, xlim = c(#,#))`

[image]

- Adjusting margins didn't help either ([Is it possible to make a forest plot output smaller/resize? Forestplot doesn´t fit the screen (using packages “meta” and “metafor” in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446097/is-it-possible-to-make-a-forest-plot-output-smaller-resize-forestplot-doesn%C2%B4t-f))

  `par(mar = c(#, #, #, #))`

  `forest(total_res$test)`
- I then tried to generate a file with the whole picture to see if its only cut off in my RStudio (https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/forest.html), playing with the width and height according to this website, also the pdf file shows the cutoff.

  `pdf(file = "forestplot.pdf", width = #, height = #)`

  `forest(total_res$test)`

  `dev.off()`

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not always work. The forest method on meta objects in R creates a window based on the number of lines in the meta-analysis and the total width of everything being displayed. This can exceed the size of the viewer window and can't always be easily resized.

There is a workaround to fix this problem. You can play with the "fontsize" and "spacing" arguments in the forest.meta function. The fs.hetstat parameter controls the size of the heterogeneity stats. Altering these parameters will make the plot smaller (vertically and horizontally).

```
library(meta)
data(Olkin1995)

m1 <- metabin(ev.exp, n.exp, ev.cont, n.cont,
              data = Olkin1995, subset = c(41, 47, 51, 59),
              sm = "RR", method = "I",
              studlab = paste(author, year))

#Default
forest(m1)
```

[image: Normal]

```
#Squished
forest(m1, fontsize = 8, spacing = .5)
```

[image: Squished]

In Rmarkdown documents, the `output.width` and `output.height` parameters can be tweaked to scale the output back to the original size.